# How to get contract object using ABI json and address with web3j?

Tags: json-rpc, web3j, abi

I worked with web3js(JavaScript) and used web3.eth.Contract with 2 params (json, address) and successfully got contract object.
Now I started to work with web3j(Java) and don`t understand how I have to work now.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Like java and javascript are totally unrelated languages, web3j is different from the javascript library with similar name. I'd suggest to start reading web3j's documentation at https://docs.web3j.io.

Comment: Yes, I found this documentation, but it doesn`t clarify what exactly I have to do.
It seems to me, that I need to deploy somehow a contract via Solidity or Truffle. Both of them I did not use before.
So, how can I deploy a contract having json and address - that is a question)
May be someone has an example ?

Comment: Last time I did something with java you had to use some utility to convert json file to a [smart contract wrapper](https://docs.web3j.io/smart_contracts/#solidity-smart-contract-wrappers). Then use that wrapper to deploy instances or interact with deployed instances, see https://docs.web3j.io/getting_started/#working-with-smart-contracts-with-java-smart-contract-wrappers. Sorry, but I did use very little of web3j so I can't help much there.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

I installed epirus wrapper, then I generated java package with command epirus solidity generate

```
-a=/root/my_json.abi -o=/root/ -p=my_java
```

(before I changed extension of my file from json to abi).
After getting this package, I could use smart contract object with his methods from json file.

Also, after installation of epirus and before generating package I used this commands

```
JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $( readlink -f $(which java) ))
JAVA_HOME=$(realpath "$JAVA_HOME"/../)
export JAVA_HOME
```

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Don`t know exactly what they do, but without them I could not use epirus.

To check if epirus ready to generate I used command

```
epirus -V
```

It returns version of wrapper. If not - use two commands above.

Ismael, thank you for the direction)